# retrieving images from data return in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

im trying to display som images in my code , already stored in my data in this way:

```html
          <div  >
            <tr v-for='(ships,index) in destroyedShipBox' :key='index'>
              <td>{{ships}}</td>
               <div v-for='(links,index1) in destroyedShipBoximages' :key='index1'>
                  {{links.type==ships?links.src:''}}
               </div>
              </tr>
          </div>
```

where my data stores this arrays of objects:

```
data() {
    return {

      destroyedShipBox:['PatrolBoat','Destroyer'],
      destroyedShipBoximages:[
        {type:'PatrolBoat',src:require('../assets/patrolBoatHorizontalView.png')},
        {type:'Submarine',src:require('../assets/submarineHorizontalView.png')},
        {type:'BattleShip',src:require('../assets/battleshipHorizontalView.png')},
        {type:'Carrier',src:require('../assets/carrierHorizontalView.png')},
        {type:'Destroyer',src:require('../assets/destroyerHorizontalView.png')},

      ],
}
```

the destroyedShipBox gets fill automatically with some JSON already fetched then destroyedShipBoximages is just a collection of all type of ships in game as well as a image of its according to its type.
Thus my logic in the html template wants to  set an image attuning with the kind of ships i already got in the destroyedShipBox array , but the the final result is this

```
PatrolBoat    /img/patrolBoatHorizontalView.63b25d8d.png----->should be an image instead of this
Destroyer     /img/destroyerHorizontalView.396ed25f.png ----->should be an image instead of this
```

simply the image don't appear...
Any advice about how to solve this problem...
thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also ease up your template logic and have only one if condition if there is a 1:1 relation between ships and their images with the following computed property:

```
computed: {
    shipsWithImages() {
    return this.destroyedShipBoximages.filter((value) => {
    if(this.destroyedShipBox.includes(value.type)) {
        return value;
    }
  })
},
```

}

Cheers,

ewatch

Comment: Happy to hear that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should assign `links.src` to `src` attribute of `img` tag like this:

```
<div>
  <tr v-for='(ships,index) in destroyedShipBox' :key='index'>
    <td>{{ships}}</td>
    <td>
      <div v-for='(links,index1) in destroyedShipBoximages' :key='index1'>
        <img :src="links.src" v-if="links.type==ships"/>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</div>
```